# Opening Ogg is failing with soundfile: "Format not recognised"

Tags: python, soundfile

```
import soundfile as sf

def convert():
    data, samplerate = sf.read('file.ogg')
    sf.write('file.wav', data, samplerate)
```

I am having error while converting ogg file to wav:

> soundfile.LibsndfileError: Error opening 'file.ogg': Format not recognised.

Comment: Have you verified that your `file.ogg` is actually a valid OGG file?

Comment: If you on Linux, try to to execute `file your_ogg_file.ogg` then you have to see something like `Ogg data, Vorbis audio, stereo, 44100 Hz, ~160000 bps, created by: Xiph.Org libVorbis I (1.3.3)`

Comment: ANALYSIS DETAILS:
General
Format : Ogg
File size : 106 KiB
Duration : 13 s 192 ms
Overall bit rate mode : Variable
Overall bit rate : 66.1 kb/s
Writing application : Lavf55.33.100

Audio
ID : 3662439923 (0xDA4C65F3)
Format : Vorbis
Format settings, Floor : 1
Duration : 13 s 192 ms
Bit rate mode : Variable
Bit rate : 128 kb/s
Channel(s) : 2 channels
Sampling rate : 16.0 kHz
Compression mode : Lossy
Stream size : 206 KiB
Writing library : Lavf55.33.100

Comment: Same for me with .wav. File returns only : WebM